# Ray tune AssertionError: HpBandSter must be installed! | Cannot run HyperBandForBOHB

Tags: ray, ray-tune

I try to use HyperBandForBOHB in ray tune, but I always get this error while all requirement has been installed:

```
AssertionError: HpBandSter must be installed!
            You can install HpBandSter with the command:
            `pip install hpbandster ConfigSpace`.
```

I uninstalled all related pkgs and install them (not from cache) from scratch, but the error still appears.

hpbandster version(0.7.4)
ConfigSpace version(0.6.0)
Ray version(2.1.0)
Python version(3.8)
Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Can you try running: `import ConfigSpace; from hpbandster.optimizers.config_generators.bohb import BOHB` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_centered' from 'scipy.signal.signaltools'
```

And I solve it by

```
 pip install statsmodels --upgrade
```